# Uncaught Error: container is not in current document

Tags: reactjs, blockly

> use blocky in React.js ,the question about the Blockly.inject

```
import React from 'react'
import Blockly from 'node-blockly'
const toolbox = `
     <xml>
       <block type="controls_if"></block>
       <block type="controls_whileUntil"></block>
     </xml>` 
class BlocklyDiv extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var workspace = Blockly.inject(this.blocklyDiv,{toolbox: toolbox});
    }
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>BlocklyDiv</h2>
            <div id="blocklyContainer">
                <div id="blocklyDiv" ref={ref => this.blocklyDiv = ref} ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
export default BlocklyDiv
```

> the error :
>   Uncaught Error: container is not in current document.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1k2N.png)

Comment: import Blockly from 'node-blockly'
--->

    import Blockly from 'node-blockly/browser'

It's OK ~

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` callback is effectively the `componentDidMount` for that JSX element.

Move the logic out of `componentDidMount` and into the `ref` callback instead.

Comment: but other people use it's ok , about this :https://github.com/jiaowochunge/DemoBlockly/blob/master/src/blocklyDiv.js#L14
how can I fix the code?
thank you for your help